# Python: a function receives a memory-intensive argument. This argument should be read-only. What is the best way to do it?

Tags: python, parameter-passing, private, readonly-attribute

A system I'm developing allows external users to develop plugins, which are basically subclasses of a predefined interface. An `initialise()` function is called which receives an argument called `data` from class `Data`. I would like to forbid the external users, who implement the subclass method `initialise(self, data)`, to make any changes to `data`. I want it to be a readonly argument.

The object `data` contains a lot of preloaded data, including possibly large dataframes. Passing a duplicate of the original argument `data` is thus undesirable. On the other hand, it is safe, as if the user changes anything in the copy it will not affect the original.

Another option is to obfuscate the original attributes using `@property` and forbidding any changes with `@atribute.setter`. The `Data` class has many attributes (around 40). It is possible, but the user can still make a mess in case they really try, and the class code will have MANY `@property`decorators, one per attribute. Still, it is so far my preferred solution.

Is there any other possible, perhaps more elegant, or more private, solution to this problem?

Comment: `@property` only provides "shallow" protection anyway - a property on `type(a)` allows you to control `a.b = c`, but not `a.b.c = d`.

Comment: The usual approach is to just document "don't mutate this, and if you do and everything breaks, that's your fault".

Comment: Maybe you could create a read-only ```memoryview``` of the object and provide a set of interfaces to read from it.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica this idea is also on the table :-)

Comment: We are all consenting adults here.